# C# and sql server

Tags: c#

I've created a database and a table with 2 fields Id and Name.
Now I want to insert  values on clicking a button the sammple code is given. it's not working.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
{
    SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand("insert into Test (Id,Name) values(5,kk);",connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Not working ?? are you getting any exception ? any error ? data is not being entered ? plz update your question with complete information and also use Parameterized query

Comment: Whats the error? Just off the cuff - u need to enclose kk in single quotes a la 'kk' - presuming thats a varchar of some sort

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Post your connection string. The error indicates that your db is not reachable from your code. So the error in your code - already pointed out below by so many folks - are immaterial - till you can connect to your db

Comment: string strConnection = "Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=yes";

Comment: With what kind of database are you trying to connect? That connection string doesn't look valid.

Comment: connection = new SqlConnection("Server=(local); ");
what about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
try
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Test (Id,Name) values(@iD, @Name)", conn, trans))
   {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.AddParameter(SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, ParameterDirection.Input, "@iD", ID);
      cmd.AddParameter(SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, "@Name", Name);

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   conn.CommitTransaction(trans);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   conn.RollbackTransaction(trans);
   throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String values should be in quotes. This has not much to do with C#, more with T-SQL

Try this, and notice the kk;

```
SqlCommand command =  
      new SqlCommand("insert into Test (Id,Name) values(5,'kk');",connection);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Also I am assuming here that `Id` is not an auto-increment field. If it is, then you should not fill it.

As a side-node you should look at parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, you need single quotes ' around the kk

```
insert into Test (Id,Name) values(5,'kk')
```

In general, you should use parameterised queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection('connection string here');    
string command = "INSERT INTO Test(Id, Name) VALUES(5, 'kk')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = command;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. String values should be between ' '
2. Verify your connection string

   ```
           //add your connection string between ""
           string connectionString = "";

           using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
           {
               cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO pdf (Id, Name) VALUES (5, 'kk')";

               conn.Open();

               conn.ExecuteNonQuery();

               conn.Close();
            }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple problems with your current code.

- You need to enclose string values in single quotes, as pointed out in other answers.
- You need to **enable remote connection to your SQL server.**

Check the following link if you are using SQL server 2008.

[How to enable remote connections in SQL Server 2008?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

and for SQL Server 2005 see:

[How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277#method1)